# bundle exec pod install -> Failed to find known source with the URL "trunk"

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm following some instructions left behind for an Xcode repository.

```
$ bundle exec pod install
Analyzing dependencies
[!] The version of CocoaPods used to generate the lockfile (1.9.3) is higher than the version of the \
current executable (1.6.1). Incompatibility issues may arise.
```

I think this leads to the error:

```
 Failed to find known source with the URL "trunk"
```

When I check the version of `pods`, I get:

```
$ pod --version
1.10.0
```

My assumption (but I could be wrong), is that I either need to run the command to it runs the newer version of `pod`, or I need to install the newer version in a different place.

***Added info***
(per comment's request)

```
$ gem list pod

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

cocoapods (1.10.1, 1.10.0)
cocoapods-core (1.10.1, 1.10.0)
cocoapods-deintegrate (1.0.4)
cocoapods-downloader (1.4.0)
cocoapods-plugins (1.0.0)
cocoapods-search (1.0.0)
cocoapods-trunk (1.5.0)
cocoapods-try (1.2.0)


$ grep -i pod Gemfile.lock
    cocoapods (1.6.1)
      cocoapods-core (= 1.6.1)
      cocoapods-deintegrate (>= 1.0.2, < 2.0)
      cocoapods-downloader (>= 1.2.2, < 2.0)
      cocoapods-plugins (>= 1.0.0, < 2.0)
      cocoapods-search (>= 1.0.0, < 2.0)
      cocoapods-stats (>= 1.0.0, < 2.0)
      cocoapods-trunk (>= 1.3.1, < 2.0)
      cocoapods-try (>= 1.1.0, < 2.0)
    cocoapods-core (1.6.1)
    cocoapods-deintegrate (1.0.4)
    cocoapods-downloader (1.2.2)
    cocoapods-plugins (1.0.0)
    cocoapods-search (1.0.0)
    cocoapods-stats (1.1.0)
    cocoapods-trunk (1.3.1)
    cocoapods-try (1.1.0)
  cocoapods
```

Comment: Can you `gem list pod` and give us the output? Also, can you `grep -i pod Gemfile.lock` ?

Comment: added both to question.

Comment: You could try a `bundle update cocoapods` and see if that helps? Your bundle has an older version to your current gemset.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue multiple times, not sure why though. To fix I run the following terminal commands in the project directory:

`sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean` (ONLY if you do not have `cocoapods-deintegrate` and `cocoapods-clean` installed)

`pod deintegrate`

`pod clean`

`pod setup`

`pod install`

From my understanding this will completely clear and reinstall the pod files. Again I am not sure what causes the issue to start with, but this works for me.

Comment: Keep in mind if you do this it's equivalent to running `pod update` as all your pods will be updated to the latest version unless you've locked the version info in the Podfile. This may have unintended consequences with newer versions of pod libraries getting installed in your project.

Comment: The above steps didn't help for me, still got the same error, had to switch to ruby 2.7 (using rbenv) then install the latest version of cocoapods supported by ruby 2.7.